# Regex ignore part of a String - Java

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing an IP, and I don't care about anything, but the IP.  Here is what I have, but I don't care what follows after the '10', and just want to know if the String matches the IP:

```
[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.(16|249)\\.10
```

What can I add into this to make it ignore everything else?  This IP will be at the very beginning of the String every time as well.

Comment: Add `.*` after the `10`? What does your string look like? How do you use the regex?

Comment: Might want to use a better regex. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew that worked! Thank you

Comment: I posted an answer with some more tweaks, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string starts with a *specific* IP pattern, and you are using `String#matches()`, just append a word boundary after `10` and use `.*` after it:

```
"(?s)\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.(?:16|249)\\.10\\b.*"
```

The `(?s)` is added to make sure you will match the whole string that can contain newlines.

Instead of a `\b` you may use `(?!\d)` (`"(?!\\d)"`) to disallow matching IPs ending with `100` rather than `10`.

**NOTE** that the first and second parts (`\\d{1,3}`) can be enhanced by replacing them with `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` and the regex would look like `"(?s)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(?:16|249)\\.10\\b.*"`.